# Como reproduzir som em um aplicativo do Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Tenho um aplicativo para Google Chrome e quero que ele emita um som toda vez que uma notificação for criada, mas em meus testes não tive muito sucesso =p

Não sei se é alguma permissão ou se realmente não tem como eu fazer isso.

Vocês sabem algum jeito? (Detalhe: Queria o arquivo js em background fizesse isso)

Comment: O que você tentou? Imagino que injetar um elemento `<audio>` via js deva funcionar.

Comment: eu tentei usar uma tag audio e js: new audio('').play; não deu certo nenhum dos 2 =/

Comment: E que formato tem o arquivo de áudio? Acho que precisa ser ogg.

Comment: Hm, acho que me enganei, veja a tabela de formatos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: nesse link não tem tabela nenhuma =p

Comment: Lá no fim tem uma tabela de compatibilidade, por formato de arquivo e browser.

Comment: Nossa, que estranho, agora deu certo =O Obrigado o/

Comment: Legal, eu já ia fazer um teste, me poupou trabalho :) Agora eu vou te dar trabalho: pode postar a solução como resposta para ajudar futuros visitantes? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou usar a Web Audio API?

```
 var context = new webkitAudioContext();
 var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
 oscillator.connect(context.destination);
 oscillator.frequency.value = 780; //frequencia do som, altere pra mudar o som que será emitido
 oscillator.start(0);
 oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + 0.5)//duração do som;
```

Se você usar a API leve em conta que o "oscillator" é destruído após o uso, pra cada som deve criar um novo.

Cross-browser: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api

Exemplo retirado de: http://pt.slideshare.net/eshiota/retrojs-escrevendo-msicas-da-era-8bits-com-javascript-e-web-audio-api

Comment: Vou tentar Lucas :) É meio difícil achar uma nota boa =O